# javascript/jquery loop result in busy waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an click event handler that dequeues a function if one is available.  I made a loop to wait for the queue.  I thought this would work but on one of my machines it results in a busy wait and freezes everything.  I'm confused about why this is a problem.  The goal is to wait for the queue to be non-empty.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

```
function handleViewClick(event){
  clickEvent = event;  // make event details available to requestReport on body-foo Q
  var body = $("body");
  while ( 0 == body.queue("foo").length ) 
    setTimeout(function(){
        handleViewClick(event);
      },
      1000);
  body.dequeue("foo");  // analyze and report on click.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me put your code in English, see if it helps.

- The `handleViewClick` function, which takes an `event`...

  - Assigns `event` to the `clickEvent` variable
  - Gets the document body and puts it in `body`
  - If the length of the queue `foo` is non-zero...

    - Set a timer to call `handleViewClick` again in one second
  - If the length of the queue `foo` is non-zero...

    - Set a timer to call `handleViewClick` again in one second
  - If the length of the queue `foo` is non-zero...

    - Set a timer to call `handleViewClick` again in one second
  - If the length of the queue `foo` is non-zero...

    - Set a timer to call `handleViewClick` again in one second
  - ...
  - Crash.

`while` loops will run until completion. `setTimeout` will run when it gets an opportunity, as soon as possible after the time specified. The two are incompatible. You are setting millions of timers and expecting the result to be different.

Did you mean `if` instead of `while`? Because that would work, if you then put the `dequeue` call in the corresponding `else`.